# How to implement tap to like animation like Instagram?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

As title, I'm currently working on an Android project. I need to implement a feature similar to "tap to like" on Instagram.

I think this feature could be described in this way. When tapping the button, a small image(heart icon on Instagram) floats from the position of the button in a random path, with fade-out effect, and finally disappear.

Any simple way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use Bezier Curves to draw the path and make the heart pic move along w/ it

Answer (score 1):

You can use library like https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

Get the particle drawable that you want. Set it up

```
new ParticleSystem(this, MAX_PARTICLES_COUNT, R.drawable.heart, LIFESPAN_MILLIS)
.setSpeedModuleAndAngleRange(speedMin, speedMax, minAngle, maxAngle)
.setFadeOut(milisecondsBeforeEnd, interpolator interpolator)
.oneShot(anchorView, numParticles);
```

Play with the settings until result that you want.

Comment: Eventually, I didn't use it. I implemented it by myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Instagram itself is using `Leonids` library.

Comment: @DayoChoul how did you implement this heart animations?

Comment: @kinsleykajiva Hi there, finally I use Bezier Curves to draw the path and make the heart pic move along w/ it